# Hashes and case statements

Tags: ruby, hash, case-statement

I have to update and add a movie title and its associated rating to an existing hash. This is the code that i have so far:

```
movies = { 
Titanic:4, 
Bestman: 3,
Agora: 2
}

puts "What would you like to do?"
choice = gets.chomp

case movies
when "add"
    puts "What movie do you want to add?"
    title = gets.chomp
    puts "What's the rating of the movie?"
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title] = rating
    puts "#{title} has been added with a rating of #{rating}."

when "update"
puts "Updated!"
when "display"
puts "Movies!"
when "delete"
puts "Deleted!"
else 
    puts "Error!"
end
```

When I run the code, I get this error "it looks like you didn't add to the movies hash"

I know the error lies somewhere between these lines:

```
case movies
when "add"
    puts "What movie do you want to add?"
    title = gets.chomp
    puts "What's the rating of the movie?"
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title] = rating
    puts "#{title} has been added with a rating of #{rating}."
```

I have been trying to figure it out but thus far have failed to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Is there an alternative way to add to my movies hash? And what is wrong with my puts code for letting the user know that his/her movie title and rating has been added?

Thank you

**EDIT**
As pointed out by Some Guy, changing the case statement from

```
case movies
```

to

```
case choice
```

resolved the issue.

What I need to learn/figure out is why the 2nd works but the 1st does not.

Comment: You probably want case choice rather than case movies

Comment: That worked! If you don't mind, can you please explain why using movies rendered my code invalid - I would appreciate your feedback, thank you!

Comment: movies is your hash, but you wanted the case statement to act on your input, which is stored in the variable 'choice'.

Comment: I don't mean to confuse you, but you should be aware that a case statement is not always equivalent to a series of if/then's.  That's because case statements use the 'case equality operator', `===`, rather than the simple equality operator `==` used by if/then.  Consider this example: `def a(b); case b; when Array; puts "array"; when String; puts "string"; end; end`.  Then `a [] # => "array"; a "cat" # => "string"`.  To do this with an if/then, you'd you have something like `if b.is_a? String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's still not clear, it may help to think of a case statement as a series of if/elsif (there are differences, but for this scenario it works), so:

```
case movies
when "add" # do stuff
```

is akin to:

```
if movies == "add"
   # do stuff
end
```

Hoping that makes it clearer.

Comment: I actually understand the first explanation better - the case statement should act on the input that the user provides and since the case statement is contained within a container called movies, it makes sense to make sure that the commands given/code written for case statements be specific to the case statement container - that is the code act on case alone.  Does that make sense? What I am essentially doing is attempting to break down the program to discrete units and write codes that work for each particular unit/make sure I know what each line of code is acting on or can affect.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
case movies
```

to

```
case choice  # because this is where your choice of what to do is being stored
```